# Is Mobile Angular UI a framework I can use for a mobile html application?

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui

Our current web application for mobile is build with jquery mobile 
https://www.bit2c.co.il/mobile 
I would like to upgrade it with better ui, plus I believe that jquery mobile js and ui are not working smooth over IPhone 4. (the nav bars, header and footer, are refusing to stay fixed ).

So I did some research and found that mobile angular UI is working pretty well over different smart phones including IPhone 4.

My question is: 
1.Is this framework well supported and will continue to grow ?
2.Is it working inside phonegap hybrid application ?
3.If using it means there is no need for jquery? and by that how all the functionality done with jquery is done with angular instead?

Please keep in mind I have little angular knowledge and I've seen there will be great change in angularJS 2.0. which leads me to concern in using this version.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anything, Angular 2.0 is more mobile-aware than 1.3.  My team has built a mobile-only application with Angular 1.3 and it works quite well. We've also wrapped it in Cordova to build native mobile apps, although there were more issues there due to third-party JavaScript. The main problem with starting a new app with Angular 1.3 today is that eventually Google will only push security fixes, and no new features will come to the framework.  If you build a one-off app, that's fine, but if you're building a new product that will keep on evolving over the next 2 years, 1.3 is not the right choice anymore.

The main challenge I would say we have is that it takes a while to load upon the first page-load.  We're a content site with little user "functionality" and while Angular has been good, I don't think it's the best solution for a plain content site; Angular is really meant for applications where you want users to interact with things on the screen without creating new pageloads for every click.